# log4j Error when trying to run mvn: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

Something is up with my maven logging where I'm just trying to install 3.3.9 into /usr/local/maven on my centos6.5 with oracle java build 1.8.0_66-b17 and I get the following when I type: `mvn` or when I follow the install guide and try to create project with `mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false`. After a few hours or re-installing and cleaning up what I thought were the issue, still getting same warning.

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.maven.cli.logging.impl.UnsupportedSlf4jBindingConfiguration).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)
```

(Edit)
It looks like when I try it with 3.0.4 I still get the no logger warning but at least it successfully builds. Still not sure why the newer versions are failing:

```
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Using following parameters for creating project from Old (1.x) Archetype: maven-archetype-quickstart:1.0
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Parameter: basedir, Value: /ebs/mvn_test
[INFO] Parameter: package, Value: com.mycompany.app
[INFO] Parameter: groupId, Value: com.mycompany.app
[INFO] Parameter: artifactId, Value: my-app
[INFO] Parameter: packageName, Value: com.mycompany.app
[INFO] Parameter: version, Value: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] project created from Old (1.x) Archetype in dir: /ebs/mvn_test/my-app
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7.132s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Nov 28 19:59:19 UTC 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/1846M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: So you downloaded Maven 3.3.9, unzipped it, added to the PATH, called `mvn` (and I mean literally `mvn` or `mvn -version`) and you had this error? If so, sounds like a bug somewhere.

Comment: are you getting this while building the project?

Comment: Not trying to build a project. Just trying to setup mvn properly. I'm pretty sure in the past I was able to run the `mvn` command and not receive this error. All I have done so far is download binary tar and can run `mvn -version` without any issues.

Comment: Looks like when I try it with maven 3.0.4 it builds the example app successfully. Not sure why newer versions are not working.